# Does Magento send the order increment_id to paypal?

Tags: paypal, transactions, magento-1.7, orders

I want to use a summary (from PayPal) of orders and compare it with a list of the increment ids provided by the magento backend.

Currently I'm doing this by opening the transactions panel in the backend and match the transaction numbers. Is there a option doing this the way described above?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30607/721) for this in magento.stackexchange:

> Yes If you are using Magento's Paypal standard module then the increment_id is sent over to Paypal and here is the proof: